# sort in 2 dimensions R

Tags: r

I have data from an image processing program that I need to piece back together. My image data are originally an array of 18 (6 x 3) wells on a microscope slide, I need to number these wells consistently so I can identify what was in each well later on. I have the approximate x and y positions (in pixels) of the wells, and I want to sort them from left to right and then top to bottom (seems simplest) and number them 1 to 18.

like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
[2,]    7    8    9   10   11   12
[3,]   13   14   15   16   17   18
```

The caveats:

-Not all wells were picked up by the image processing program, so sometimes there are less than 18.

-Not all wells in the same row or column are on the exact same x or y, they seem to float around within 20-40 pixels.

-Not all images are centered on the same point or at the exact same magnification so well positions are not reliable enough to code for a range.

Example of data:

```
   Well BBXLeft BBYTop
1     0      39    637
2     1      43   1218
3     2     596    630
4     3     610   1212
5     4    1161    633
6     5    1164   1207
7     6    1710    623
8     7    1715   1202
9     8    2267    620
10    9    2271   1199
11   10    2824    617
12   11    2845   1197
13   12      35     57
14   13     593     53
15   14    1709     45
16   15    2262     41
17   16    2820     38
```

Or in reproducible form from `dput`:

```
wells <- structure(list(Well = 0:16, BBXLeft = c(39L, 43L, 596L, 610L,1161L, 1164L, 1710L, 1715L, 2267L, 2271L, 2824L, 2845L, 35L, 593L, 1709L, 2262L, 2820L), BBYTop = c(637L, 1218L, 630L, 1212L, 633L, 1207L, 623L, 1202L, 620L, 1199L, 617L, 1197L, 57L, 53L, 45L, 41L, 38L)), .Names = c("Well", "BBXLeft", "BBYTop"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

Wells are out of order from image analysis program
This example missing well #15 (or 14 if count from 0)

Ideal output would be a new column with the left-right, top-bottom well numbers (or even "battleship" coordinates)

Sorry if this is a bit of a homework question but I really don't know how to do this efficiently without hard-coding the cutoffs. I'm using R because it's the only language I have a grasp on and I have other code ready to go written around this problem.

Comment: It's unclear what you want the format of your output to be.  I'm guessing BBXLeft and BBYtop are your x and y coordinates you want to place in a matrix or data.frame, but your explanation is poorly phrased and too long.. Keep it simple: I have this.. and I want this.. This is what I've tried.

Comment: I would 2nd @NathanG's comment.  Also, with regards to the missing well.. how is one to determine which well specifically is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below will help you to sort your wells according to the pixel location. 
However, perhaps more importantly is the following --
These are your WellNumber labels plotted against the pixel location.  **Is this labeling scheme intentional, or are the well locations getting shuffled when labeling the image data?**

[image]

---

In order to sort your data, we simply need a natural break, such as image size.  In the example below I chose 500, but you can adjust as needed.

```
# sort & plot the pixel corners, to get an idea for where the boundaries re
sort(wells$BBXLeft)
sort(wells$BBYTop)

plot(x=wells$BBXLeft, y=wells$BBYTop)

# add an NA for the missing value (we cant just ignore it)
wells[18,] <- c(NA, 1100, 30) 

imgSize <- 500
nrows <- 3
ncols <- 6

# Assign row and col number based on boundaries set every 'imgSize'
#  Note that rows are reversed, top to bottom
wells$row <- cut(wells$BBYTop,  breaks=seq(imgSize*nrows, 0, -imgSize), label=1:nrows)
wells$col <- cut(wells$BBXLeft, breaks=seq(0, imgSize*ncols, imgSize), label=1:ncols)

# your battleship coordinates
wells$battleship <- paste0("(", wells$row, ", ", wells$col, ")")


# then to sort it,  sorting by rows, then by cols
orderedWells <- wells$WellNo[order(wells$row, wells$col)]

# if you want to lay it out nicely, use a matrix
matrix(orderedWells, nrow=nrows, ncol=ncols, byrow=TRUE)

 #          [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 #     [1,]   12   13   NA   14   15   16
 #     [2,]    0    2    4    6    8   10
 #     [3,]    1    3    5    7    9   11
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the slow response, I haven't quite integrated this into the rest of my code but it looks like it does what I need. I did now know about the "cut" function. I wish I didn't have to hardcode the imgSize, I have hundreds of images to go through and there are always exceptions, I will try to build in something to flag potential errors.

Comment: @GregS, No prob.   You do not necessarily have to hard code the image size. You can find the intervals programmatically.  For example, using `diff()` and finding gaps above a given threshold.